# Why was an edit adding a class tag to a question about that class rejected?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, rejected-edits, reject-reasons

I recently suggested a [tag edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35064195) to a question entitled [Spring Rest Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957502/spring-rest-template). The question asks about the benefit of returning an instance of Spring's `RestTemplate` in the main function, so it seemed natural to add the tag corresponding to that class. However, the edit was rejected (2 reject votes and 1 accept vote) because *"it introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question"*. From my current understanding, I fail to see how this is the case, because the class wasn't just mentioned incidentally or in passing, but was the primary subject of the question. However, I might be mistaken, in such case I think a plausible explanation could help me avoid suggesting similar edits in the future. Why do you think this edit was rejected?

Comment: Edits typically fix more than just a missing tag especially a 3 year old question with an answer

Comment: @SecurityHound Tag edits are not typical by definition. I don't see the issue here. Can you explain how the fact that the question is 3 year old is relevant?

Comment: "Edits typically fix more than just a missing tag especially a 3 year old question" - In opposite, I would expect that a 3 years old question to be in a good form, so it actually requires only small edits. Well, the title - "Spring Rest Template" - is plain bad (instead of **summarizing**  the question, the title just *lists keywords*). But the question body looks OK. "Tag edits are not typical by definition" - no, tag edits obey common edit rules. That is, if a question post requires several fixes, tag-only edits without full edit privileges are NOT ok.

Comment: I don't find the current duplicates to be applicable to the referenced question, so I voted to reopen. But I strongly recommend to add "specific-question" tag to your post, so instead of general guides you will be able to get **specific** answers for your case.

Comment: *""Tag edits are not typical by definition" - no, tag edits obey common edit rules"* Yes, by not typical I was referring to the fact that they are less statistically significant compared to their counterparts, not that they don't obey common edit rules. I was using the term with meaning implied by the first commenter.

Comment: *"I'm not sure I can offer you much help if you are unwilling to put the bare minimum to even understand the particularities of the questions you're marking as a duplicate."* - I'm not sure there are that many important particularities here. You submitted a tag only edit to a question which needed far more changes than just the addition of a tag. This is _very_ clearly answered in the duplicate: *"I know you are editing to fix the tags, but you should look at the whole post and see if there's anything else you can fix there"*

Comment: @Nickistired *"I'm not sure there are that many important particularities here. "* I was referring to the fact that the user who marked the question as a duplicate did not even make the minimum effort to comprehend what it's about, e.g. by referring to a technology that had nothing to do with the specific question.

Comment: @Nickistired *"You submitted a tag only edit to a question which needed far more changes than just the addition of a tag."* Can you expand on the many changes that the question needed? I personally felt that the question looked acceptable, though I'm asking this question on meta specifically to know what I might have overlooked.

Comment: [In 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter), about 50 million Stack Overflow posts had their formatting broken by [the weird syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter), so yes, statistically there is *** *** ***always*** *** *** more to do than a tag edit. The example post wasn't broken that way, but the formatting is still off and ought to be fixed.

Comment: cont' - (It being an external dependency is a bad excuse for not ***implementing*** it properly.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen What external dependency? Can you link to the question in question?

Comment: This meta question mentions that the edit was rejected because "it introduces tags that do not help to define the topic", however the comments suggest that it was rejected because it failed to fix other problems in the question. Those are two different reasons, so which one is it? Is the tag not appropriate, if so, why not, or are there other problems, if so, which ones? Or maybe both? I think it would be good if someone provides an answer to this meta question to clarify.

Comment: Spring contains thousands of classes (and Spring Boot adds a couple more), we really don't need tags per class. But I guess RestTemplate would be an exception to the rule given that it is pretty much an API on their own about which you can write a complete book. I'm not apposed to the spring-resttemplate tag or its existence on this particular question. It is a pretty unresearched question, but meh. Very answerable.

Answer (score 3):

Tags are mainly used to bring questions in front of the right experts. Answerers  are likely to have filters set-up so they see interesting questions for them to answer. Wrongly tagged questions should therefor get edits asap to make those questions answerable by the right crowd.

I doubt your edit would achieve that goal.

First of all you claim you add *the tag corresponding to that class*. But that tag has no [tag wiki nor excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-resttemplate/info) so we have to go on the name alone that the usage of the tag  is appropriate on that question.

Secondly I doubt many new experts will see that question, given it is tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) and the [top 3 answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-resttemplate/topusers) all have tag badges in those main tags.

Lastly there are only 250 questions in that tag in three years time. I doubt that tag is the best way to chop-up the massive [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) and [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot) tags to drive answers to interesting questions.

If you're aiming to improve older questions I would take these points into consideration:

- improve the whole post: title, body and tags
- don't make tag only-edits when you don't have [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)
- don't add tags that don't have an excerpt (instead consider adding a tag wiki and excerpt first. Do read [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one))
- don't add tags that don't help bringing the question in front of the right experts
- Explain why you made the edit (*Missing tag* is factually correct but doesn't  inform a reviewer what the pressing issue was that the tag got added by you, right now)

Some of these are subjective points and what I find a helpful tag might not be considered useful by those that review your edits. The non-robo reviewers watch for quality additions to existing content. Just adding a tag barely is.

Comment: _Tags are mainly used to bring questions in front of the right experts_ That is one main use, but there is another important use: organize questions, make them searchable, quickly confirm the question is relevant when viewing it, _for future visitors_. Even without a wiki or excerpt this is helpful, I doubt that many visitors even know excerpts and wikis exist, but they do see the tag which tells them what the question is about.